# Is there a log file that records the reason for a wake-up?

Tags: power-management

My Acer Swift SF314-57 (2019) laptop computer running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS wakes up from suspend at unexpected times.  Is there a log that records the reason for a wake-up?  I have some precise times of when it happened but need to know why (in order to then prevent it).

And if there is no such log or record by default, is it possible to adjust a debug level somewhere or something like that so that in the future these events will be recorded?

Answer (score 8):

if you can this is the command:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep Wake-up
[sudo] password for rinzwind: 
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
```

These are 2 others (RTC clock, and keyboard):

```
Wake-up Type: APM Timer
Wake-up Type: PCI PME
```

systemd does not record the reason,

On Thinkpads there is also a [thinkpad_acpi](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/laptops/thinkpad-acpi.txt). From the documentation:

> `wakeup_reason`:
>
> - Set to 1 if the system is waking up because the user
>   requested a bay ejection.
> - Set to 2 if the system is
>   waking up because the user requested the system to
>   undock.
> - Set to zero for normal wake-ups or wake-ups
>   due to unknown reasons.

Comment: I look forward to trying this out after I sort out the bigger issue I just posted.  :(

Comment: Just a FYI: I woke my computer up from suspend by pressing a key on the keyboard, but dmidecode reports `Wake-up Type: Power Switch`. Perhaps the BIOS is responsible for setting this parameter correctly, and doesn't?

Comment: Ok, my system is finally running again.  The Acer also reports "Power Switch" after waking up by key press.